# Динамическая компиляция класса java

Tags: java, компиляция

При компиляции Diagnostic выдает package org.apache.log4j does not exist

Имею вот такой метод, который в рантайме должен компилировать исходник java.

```
public static void compile(final File file, final JavaFileObject... objects) {

    System.setProperty("java.home", "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_45");
    final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), Charset.defaultCharset());

    final Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = new ArrayList<JavaFileObject>(Arrays.asList(objects));

    String[] compileOptions = new String[] { "-d", file.getAbsolutePath() };
    final Iterable compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);
    final JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null,
            new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(objects)));
    final boolean result = task.call();
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("Compilation was successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compilation failed");
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            System.err.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
    }
    try {
        fileManager.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В File путь D:\project\src\main\resources
В JavaFileObject приходит например вот такой исходник:

```
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Audi implements Car {
private String engine;

private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public void start() {
LOGGER.info("The engine starts");
setEngine("start");
}

@Override
public void stop() {
LOGGER.info("The engine stops");
setEngine("stop");
}

public String getEngine() {
return this.engine;
}

public void setEngine(final String engine) {
this.engine = engine;
}
}
```

Если убрать Logger, то все компилиться нормально. Как с этим бороться подскажите пожалуйста?

С наилучшими пожеланиями!

Comment: не хватает библиотеки org.apache.log4j в classpath

Comment: Интересно то что в класспасе она есть. В исходнике Audi.java еклипс не ругается. Но когда именно компилю в рантайме, то получается такая ситуация...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного исправил ваш код и у меня компилируется и выполняется без ошибок. Я проверил в командной строке.

```
public static void compile(final File file) {
    final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
    final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

    List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
    optionList.add("-classpath");
    optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + System.getProperty("path.separator") + "/log4j-1.2.17.jar");

    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnit
            = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(file));
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
            null,
            fileManager,
            diagnostics,
            optionList,
            null,
            compilationUnit);
    final boolean result = task.call();
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("Compilation was successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compilation failed");
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            System.err.format("Error on line %d in %s", diagnostic.getLineNumber(), diagnostic);
        }
    }
    try {
        fileManager.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил. Вылезло такое                                                                       Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: @Dron4K обновил ответ